# How to execute the set path=c:\Project Work\jdk1.8.0_66-x64\jre\bin;%PATH% command from C#

Tags: c#, cmd

I am trying to run an executable JAR file and it has to run using jre version 1.8.
when I run this command manually from CMD I am getting the jre version as 1.8.
set path=c:\Project Work\jdk1.8.0_66-x64\jre\bin;%PATH%

How can I run this command from C#. I tried the following code but not able to execute the command from c#.

```
try
            {
                string command = "set path=c:\\Project Work\\jdk1.8.0_66-x64\\jre\bin;%PATH%";
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
                    new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);



                procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

                procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

                System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
                proc.Start();

                string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

                Console.WriteLine(result);
                Console.WriteLine(procStartInfo.WorkingDirectory);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception objException)
            {
                // Log the exception
            }
```

Please provide your inputs to execute the command.

Comment: Use `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable` instead.

Comment: @Evk, you can also add your variables to the `Environment` property of `ProcessStartInfo`. That way you don't pollute the environment of the calling process. Not that it matters much in this particular case, though.

Comment: @Joey thanks for info, didn't know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to execute the command by following the below steps
1. I have written a batch file with the command 
set path=c:\Project Work\jdk1.8.0_66-x64\jre\bin;%PATH%
2. I have named the batch file and executed the batch file from C# program in the following way.

```
string abc = "abc";
        string def = "123";
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Users\\90008121\\Desktop\\ClassPathbatch.bat";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("{0} {1}", abc, def);
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();
        Console.ReadLine();
```

3. Finally the requirement is met.